# How to prove implication 'If A and B are disjoint then |A| + |B| ≤ 10'

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, set-theory

> Let $N = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10\}$ and $A$ and $B$ be subsets of $N$.
>
> Decide whether the implication is true or false.
>
> If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint then $|A| + |B| \leq 10$.

I think it's true and I understand why it is but I can't seem to express it in proof talk. Any tips?

Comment: $10=|N|\geq |A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|=|A|+|B|$, where the last equation is due to $A\cap B=\emptyset$ and the first inequality due to $N\supset A\cup B$.

Comment: How do you spot that wow. Anyways, thanks that's what I was looking for

Comment: Like everyone, by having seen someone do something similar before.

Comment: Or simply: if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint then $|A|+|B|=|A\cup B|\le|N|=10,$ where the inequality is due to $A\cup B\subset N.$

Comment: @owl when I see something I haven't done before and I can't do it I always feel down as if I was supposed to work it out on my own. I'm starting to realize everyone learns everything they know. Thanks